# get method request value=url not work php

Tags: error-handling

Please give me the solution

I need solution for this example

www.example-site.com/?url=http://mysite its not work. Its getting error page or redirecting to home page.

I tried this on same host many sites. But not done

$url= $_GET['url']; 
   echo $url;

i use this code. Its code no any problem. But i hav problem with host cpanrl. The host is not allowed get reguest send uRL with http:// when i submit on browser index.php?url=http://anything then i got error page or its redrecting to home page...

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask Unfortunately "not work" tells us (or at least me) nothing. What are you trying to do? What happens? Do you get an error? What did you expect to happen? Please help us help you!

Comment: <?php $url= $_GET['url']; echo $url; ?>  i use this code... its code no any problem.. but i hav problem with host cpenal...  the host is not allowed get reguest send uRL with http://    when i submit on browser index.php?url=http://anything    then i got error page or its redrecting to home page...